# Where do I find free SVG Illustrations?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration, resource-recommendations

I know, I know. Good design is not for free. I am just looking if there are any pages like Unsplash just for illustrations. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Never mind the downvote. I support this question, because I often need  basic and nonartistic cliparts such as generic menu icons for desktop apps, traffic signs, flags etc.  And those should indeed be free without attribution.

Answer (score 2):

- Free Illustrations: https://lukaszadam.com/illustrations
- Humaaans: https://www.humaaans.com
- Drawkit: https://www.drawkit.io/
- Open Doodles: https://opendoodles.com
- Absurd Design: https://absurd.design
- Freepik: https://freepik.com

Comment: WARNING! 'Free' can mean many different things. Some licences can still require attribution or a link-back. Read the licence of an asset carefully before using it, especially in for-profit and commercial contexts.

Comment: @PieBie - very true. Best to look for artwork that is distributed with a Creative Commons CC0 1.0 Public Domain licence. There's no need to attribute these. There aren't many sites that do this, however openclipart.org is one, and so does Humaans. Other's like DrawKit are problematic, as their licence contains some prohibitions: e.g. "Don't sell unaltered copies of icons and illustrations, for example on posters, prints, mugs, or t-shirts".

Answer (score 2):

Free illustrations for personal and commercial uses:

- [illustAC](https://en.ac-illust.com/)
- [Openclipart](https://openclipart.org/)
- [Highlights](https://www.highlights.design/)
- [Scale by Flexiple](https://2.flexiple.com/scale/home)